# Aligning image on top, and text to the bottom-right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the image on top, and the text on the bottom-right. How would I do that? Thanks.

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
img {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>

<img src = 'http://tokyodesu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cat2.jpg'>
This is a cat. Look at it closely, for it is not a dog.

</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that what you already have?

Comment: Um. No. The text is on the right, but it's not on the bottom.

Comment: @Zoheiry You see the text doesn't hit the bottom border of the div right?

Comment: I see what you mean, i thought you meant on the bottom of the image not the container

Comment: @Zoheiry no, i mean the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in a separate container (inside the outer container), that you position absolutely. For the image, use `height: auto;` to preserve the proportions without distortion:

```
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
.bottomright {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right:0px;
}
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

--

```
<div id = 'outer'>
<img src = 'http://tokyodesu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cat2.jpg'>
<div class="bottomright">
This is a cat. Look at it closely, for it is not a dog.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image may overlapped the text if the div of the text is absolute. I do not want that.

Comment: Well, you won't get bottom-alignement with any other positioning. You can add an according `padding-bottom` to the outer container to make space for the absolutely positioned text at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To align something to the bottom of a container, simply have the container `position: relative;` and the text you want to align `position: absolute; bottom: 0`
and to prevent image from overlapping, just add `padding-bottom: x` where x is the height of the text.

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: bottom;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.align-bottom {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0
}
img {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>

<img src = 'http://tokyodesu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cat2.jpg'>
<div class='align-bottom'>This is a cat. Look at it closely, for it is not a dog.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The image may overlapped the text if the div of the text is absolute;

Comment: I do not want the image to overlap the text.

Answer (score 0):

using `display:table-cell` on #outer will allow you to position the text bottom right without absolutely positioning the text.  You can then absolutely position the image to the top left, and make sure that you put enough padding on #outer to at least match the height of the image.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4toLqLp/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outer {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
text-align: right;
display: table-cell;    
}

#outer img {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(0%);
}

#outer p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>

<img src = 'http://tokyodesu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cat2.jpg'>
<p>This is a cat. Look at it closely, for it is not a dog.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution I found while having similar situation was using figure and figcaption HTML5 structure and handling ficaption with CSS.

```css
figcaption {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px; /*adjust here*/
    left: 190px; /*and here*/
    color: white;
    font: normal 15px verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/2XOL4zsm6V0nm/giphy.gif" alt="Leonidas with shield in the rain">
  </img>
  <figcaption>
  &#169;giphy.com
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```